# How to Look up SQL Database Information

Tags: sql, schema

I am completely new to SQL. If you receive access to a new SQL database, how do you look up all the different tables, the relationship between each of the tables, and what information is captured within each column?

Comment: That will **heavily depend** on which **concrete RBDMS** you're using - there's hardly any mechanisms defined in the SQL language itself

Comment: Depends on database my little knowledge about  Redshift , postgres, SQLServer have dedicated schema `InformationSchema` , Snowflake has one, Oracle has sys and user tables

Comment: Typically that information will be made available by the SQL client you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL Server, you can use this command: `sp_help 'schemaname.tablename'` to see a full breakdown of a particular table.

This gives you columns with their respective sizes, indexes and constraints. In the constraints section you will see a subsection with the constrain type = 'FOREIGN KEY' as well as the actions (if any)

If you want a list of tables and schemas in a particular database, (Again using MSSQL Server) simply use this,

```
select ss.name as 'Schema Name', st.name as 'Table Name' from sys.tables st join sys.schemas ss on st.schema_id = ss.schema_id
```